# How to make PreparedStatement.setXXX() dynamic based on type of column values

Tags: java, jdbc

I have to update table using values from a data file which contains all the rows. Now I am using JDBC batches. Data files contains 100s of columns and millions of rows.

For e.g. data file contains 3 columns two rows to make it simple

```
1,ABC,DEF
2.GHI,JKL

PreparedStatement pstmt = connection.prepareStatement(insert);
                //how to find type
                pstmt.setInt(1, 2);
                pstmt.setString(2, "GHI");
                pstmt.setString(3, "JKL");
                pstmt.addBatch();
                pstmt.executeBatch();
```

Now my question is at run time based on the data coming from data file how do I find that I need to call `setInt` or `setString` and more importantly how many times I need to call `setXXX` for that `addBatch()`. This seems like for each table I need to have dedicated preparedStatements. More importantly I need to find how many times I should call setObject at run based on the number of columns which is in data  ile? Is there anyway  I can make this generic?

I am new to JDBC please guide. Thanks in advance.

Comment: You still need to generate your query which will be something like "insert into table (column1, column2, .... columnX) values (?, ?, ... ?). Are you generating a specific query for each datafile? I understand that you need a generic way to insert data into a table without having fixed queries in your code, is that what you need?

Comment: Yes @Martin you got it right. I need some generic solution with dynamic query which is different for different files.

Comment: Well, seems like Casey has given you the first part of what you need, then you only need to generate the insert query dinamically counting the amount of fields... The issue is that you won't have any validation, the proper response to your question will depend alot on your requierements...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use setObject(int index, Object obj). JDBC then determines the correct type.

Answer (score 0):

The `PreparedStatement` has a method `setObject(int, Object)`. The documentation states

> If arbitrary parameter type conversions are required, the method setObject should be used with a target SQL type.

If you have an SQL statement like

```
Select * From table Where value1 = ? and value2 = ?
```

you have to call the `setXXX` methods two times. They are used to specify the wildcard values (marked ny `?`) for the SQL statement that the `PreparedStatement` instance represents. The number of calls is therefore dependent of your SQL statement that is referenced by your variable `insert`. The `int` argument of the `setXXX` methods refers to the position of the variable in the SQL statement with `setXXX(1, object)` referring to the first wildcard and so on.

Of course, you have to repeat the same amount of calls to `setXXX` for each query you add the the batch that you want to execute at the end.

Answer (score -1):

You can use like below snippet. Check statement.setObject documentation for further details. The "rs" in the below snippet is a resultset got by executing some query from one table. The "query" in the below snippet is some insert or update query into different table. The below example states selection from one table and insertion into some other table while dynamically identifying the column type. Note: Table column types should match else exception will be thrown.

```
PreparedStatement statement = connection.prepateStatement( query );
ResultSetMetaData rsmd = rs.getMetaData();
while( rs.next() )
{    
    for( int i = 1 ; i <= rsmd.getColumnCount() ; i++ )
    {
        statement.setObject( i, rs.getObject(i), rsmd.getColumnType(i) );
    }
}
```